# Always ignore specific folders from remote repository

Tags: php, git, laravel, github

I have this project in the remote repository, and I need to configure it so that I can always send any files (push), but that only SOME files are available and visible, that is, it always receives everything I send but only returns Some folders.

- push: send the A,B,C,D and E folders
- pull/status/checkout: show/read only the A,B,C folders (D and E ignored)

So for example tomorrow I will send the F, G and H folders and the remote repository will receive it. But after that I will try to "checkout/pull/status" and will show ONLY A,B,C (D,E,F,G,H ignored)folders again and forever and ever.

In short, I need the remote repository to receive EVERYTHING but only make part of it available.

Comment: but does it work "from repo to client"? i know it works from client to repo

Comment: This is not what .gitignore is for.  This is generally not what git is for.

Answer (score 1):

Push and fetch are not *file* based, they're *commit* based.

When you connect your client Git to a server Git, you choose whether you are doing this to *get* commits (`git fetch`), or to *give them* commits (`git push`).  But what you get or give is *whole commits*, never "a file" or "a folder" (directory).  Thus, your examples are wrong.

Note that any one commit always contains a *complete snapshot* of its tree.  That is, if you have `a/file1.txt`, `a/file2.txt`, `b/file3.txt`, and `c/file4.txt` in your repository, and you touch *one* of these files and make a commit, the new commit has copies of *all four files*.  (To save space, it *re-uses* the unmodified originals, but the commit really does contain all four files.)  When you send this commit to another Git, you send the *whole commit*, not just part of the commit.

If you put the file in, they can get the file out—and by default, they will get *all* the files.  Git does support something called a "sparse checkout", which you can (ab?)use for this kind of purpose, but chances are good that this is the wrong way to go about this.

People who ask this question are, about 93.4% of the time,<sup>1</sup> trying to store configuration files in their repository, but don't want those configuration files copied out to clients (except, sometimes, as initial default configurations).  Again, this is the *wrong way to do this:* instead of storing *the* configuration files, have your system store *default* configuration files.  Clients will pick up these *default* files as usual; clients who set up their own *actual* configurations will use their configuration instead of, or overriding, the defaults; and there will be no conflict between "my local configuration"—which is never checked in to this repository at all—and "the sample and/or default configurations", which *are* checked into this repository.

---

<sup>1</sup>This statistic made up on the spot, just like [42.7% of all statistics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000HLJWIS).